# Simplest Paracompact Space not Compact

Tags: general-topology

Which is the simplest example of paracompact but not compact space that you know?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

A countable infinite discrete space.

Answer (score 1):

The set of real numbers, as any metric space.

Comment: Any *non-compact* metric space.